# To what extent should you prove something in math contests?

Tags: proof-writing, soft-question, contest-math

Next year, I'll be attending the IMO and although I've done many math contests over the years, most of the questions wanted numerical answers and the ones that required a proof were basic and simple so I'm not really used to formal proof writing; in fact in math class, my teacher always tells me that I do a lot of the steps in my head and although she knows that I know how to prove something, I can't simply do some of the steps in my head.

Example:

> Prove for integers numbers $a_1, a_2,..., a_n$, there are integers $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ that satisfy $a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + ... + a_nx_n = d$ where $d = gcd(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$.

My proof:

> Assume this is true for all the natural numbers less than $n$ and now we'd like to prove it for $n$(here, I just assume the reader knows Bezout's Identity).Let $d' = gcd(a_1,a_2,...,a_{n-1})$ so we have $d = gcd(d', a_n)$. There are integers(for example, this is one of the parts she says i do in my head) $y_1, y_2,...,y_{n-1}$ such that $a_1y_1+a_2y_2+...+a_{n-1}y_{n-1} = d'$. We also know there are integers $x,y$ such that $d'x + a_ny = d$(again, this is another one of those instances).

Now, I've been trying to stop myself from doing this but it got me thinking, to what extent should I prove something? What I mean is, what should I assume the person who's reviewing my proof knows? Is it just basic arithmetics? Properties of certain things such as GCD and LCM? Basic properties such as $gcd(a,b) = gcd(a, c) = 1$ iff $gcd(a,bc) = 1$?  I know this might be too broad but I'm just asking for proofs in number theory and not geometry, algebra, etc.

P.S: If you think this question doesn't feet the criteria of math.se, what's an appropriate place to post this question?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Congratulations on attending the IMO.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Thank you so much:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I were grading this proof, the questions I would have are:

1. It looks like you are proceeding by induction. Have you established the base case?
2. How do you know $d=\text{gcd}(d', a_n)$?

Note, I am not concerned about the existence of $y_1,\dots,y_{n-1}$, since that follows from the induction hypothesis.

3. How do you know such $x$ and $y$ exist? (This is the same as establishing the base case for the induction.)

It's not so much a matter of what the *reader knows* but rather what *you* are able to justify. Given that the whole point of the problem is showing that the GCD of a bunch of numbers can be written as an integer combination of those numbers, you should definitely justify that for the case $n=2$, and not just assume it.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what my teacher says. I do these steps in my head: $(a_1,a_2,...,a_n) = ((a_1,a_2,...,a_{n-1}),a_n)$, for the basis of the induction, I'm using Bezout's Identity and the existence of such $x$ and $y$ is, again, because of the induction hypothesis where $n = 2$.

Comment: @BornaAhmadzade As this answer says, you need to prove a base case. If the base case is $n=1$ then you cannot use $n=2$ as an “induction hypothesis.” If the base case is $n=2$ then it’s a base case and again not a hypothesis.

Comment: @BornaAhmadzade This question is asking you to *prove* (generalized) Bezout's Identity, so you should not use it in your proof. In particular you should prove the case $n=2$ as your base case and also use that to justify the existence of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @kccu Well so you sort of answered my question. I always thought the existence of integers $x$ and $y$ such that $ax + by = gcd(a,b)$ is sort of like "common knowledge" in IMO so I didn't really think I needed to prove it. But if it were a whole different question whose proof involved Bezout's Identity, would I still have to prove it?

Comment: @DavidK Well, for the induction, you only need $n-1$ and $2$ so I didn't think I need it for $n=1$(which is trivial in my opinion. $gcd(a) = a$)

Comment: @BornaAhmadzade Again it's not about what is general knowledge, but rather about whether you are able to justify your claims. If the question wasn't proving Besout's identity, then it's a tough call. You *may* be okay to just cite the result, but if you want to play it safe then I would provide a proof.

Comment: @BornaAhmadzade I did not advise using $n=1$ as a base case. You didn’t sat what base case you had in mind, so I considered the likely possibilities. Obviously you’re better off with base case $n=2$ if you use your inductive step.

Comment: That’s just one more reason you should never leave your reader guessing what the base case is.

Comment: @DavidK, would you please consider writing a formal proof for this problem?